# Jump to anchor via select menu w/o submit using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

We have a select menu used to jump to various s on a page. Written (by someone else) a few years ago. We recently upgraded to the current jquery and it no longer works. I think it's a simple fix, but my javascript skills are weak.

Action wanted: jump to anchor based on ID in select menu without needed to press submit.

current code for the select menu:

```
<?php 
echo "<select id='subscale' style='float:right'>";
echo "<option id=''>Jump to a Teaching Tip</option>";
foreach($scales as $scale) {
    echo "<optgroup label='".$scale["Scale"]["name"]."'/>";
    foreach($scale["Subscale"] as $subscale) {
    echo "<option id='".$subscale["id"]."'>".$subscale["name"]."</option>";
    }
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    // select#subscale: on select, send user to selected subscale
    $("select#subscale").change(function() {
        location.hash = "item-" + $(this).find("[@selected]")[0].id;
    });
});
```

I believe that @selected is no longer supporting in jquery, but removing the @ sign doesn't help.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `:selected` selector to find the option.

```
$(function() {
    $("#subscale").change(function() {
        location.hash = "item-" + $(this).find("option:selected")[0].id;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `value` attribute here, like this:

```
<?php 
echo "<select id='subscale' style='float:right'>";
echo "<option value=''>Jump to a Teaching Tip</option>";
foreach($scales as $scale) {
  echo "<optgroup label='".$scale["Scale"]["name"]."'/>";
  foreach($scale["Subscale"] as $subscale) {
    echo "<option value='".$subscale["id"]."'>".$subscale["name"]."</option>";
  }
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

then your code becomes even simpler with [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#subscale").change(function() {
        location.hash = "item-" + $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick - this is a little cleaner and using value makes a little more sense.

Comment: @Voodoo - I would go this route personally, since you'll also have more valid IDs

Answer (score 0):

Use `<option value="#destination">` to store the destination anchor id, and then create a hook to watch for changes, just like Josiah posted. Except look up the anchor #fragment from the option's value attribute using `val()`.

*Example:*

```
<select id="chooser">
    <option value="#apple">I really like apples</option>
    <option value="#orange">Give me an orange any day</option>
    <option value="#grape">Grapes are the best</option>
</select>

<div id="apple">
    Let me talk to you about Apples.
</div>
<div id="orange">
    Let me talk to you about Oranges.
</div>
<div id="grape">
    Let me talk to you about Grapes.
</div>

   :
   :
   :

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#chooser').change(function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work as a general solution for overriding the destination anchor

```
<select id="chooser">
<option value="#apple">I really like apples</option>
<option value="#orange">Give me an orange any day</option>
<option value="#grape">Grapes are the best</option>
</select>

<div id="apple">
   Let me talk to you about Apples.
</div>
<div id="orange">
   Let me talk to you about Oranges.
</div>
<div id="grape">
   Let me talk to you about Grapes.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         $(document).on("click", "a[href^='#']", function () {
             event.preventDefault();
             $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 500);
         });
     });
</script>
```